# Angular 2+ custom date pipe names

Tags: angular

Angular date pipes are very practical to format date.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Is it possible to create custom date/time format string?
I'm aware that we can use this:

```
{{myDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyy - HH:ss'}}
```

What I want is define a global custom name, with the existing ones; `short`, `medium` and `long` etc.

```
{{myDate | date: 'myOwnString'}}
```

and myOwnString should look like this; `dd.MM.yyy - HH:ss`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606333/how-i-can-create-angular-custom-date-pipe see if this can help you.

Comment: @aviboy2006 Thank you, that definitely solves my problem. Although I hoped for an another solution with w/o writing own pipe.  Maybe I'll write a feature request.

Comment: you can write custom pipe also. there is provision to do.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you could without writing custom pipe, is to define the constant format strings  inside `constant.ts`

```
   export enum DateFormats{
        Medium = "dd.MM.yyy - HH:ss"
        Short = "dd.MM.yyy"
    }
```

and whenever you use it inside the component, assign it to component field

```
@Component({
})
export class SomeComponent{
   DATE_FORMATS = DateFormats
}
```

and after this, you can use inside the HTML

```
<div> {{myDate | date: DATE_FORMATS.Short}}
 </div>
```